# 4k 60hz only on Wayland, while i can get 4k 120hz on X11 (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, wayland, 4k-monitor

So if I install Nvidia Driver version 510, Ubutnu uses Wayland by default but I cannot get 120hz on my 4k screen, only 4k 60hz.

if I install Nvidia Driver version 470, Ubuntu uses X11 by default and i can get 4k 120hz.

the reason i need wayland is for fractional scaling, on X11 the fractional scaling only works on 60hz, but on 100hz or 120hz the scaling distort the image.

i have Nvidia 1080Ti, and my TV is Samsung Q80T (which supports 4k 120hz).

and I know 60hz is enough, but in my case, when 60hz is used the TV will have input delay (mouse moves on screen after i actually move the mouse which is annoying).

If someone faced such a thing and found a solution please let me know.

Comment: Hmmm... the lag you are describing sounds like you have enabled post processing effects. These should be turned off when you are using the TV as a display for your computer or when you are using it for gaming. The specs of the TV you indicated do not actually give the actual refresh rate but indicate a "motion rate" of 120 for some models and 240 for others. This is usually a post processing effect-- the actual refresh rate is probably only 60Hz. Choose the driver that works best, even if it's an older driver. Older drivers tend to be more stable

Comment: @Nmath on the TV i can select the source type, i can chose PC or Blueray player, if i chose PC the lag is gone but the picture quality is so bad and not usable for coding/webviewing, it is more tailored for gaming.

Comment: What exactly makes the picture quality so bad when it is set to PC? Unfortunately the solution to your problem likely has to do with figuring out the settings on your TV. TVs default settings are not configured to be used as displays. You'll definitely need to disable most post-processing effects to get rid of the delay. If it's like any of the other TVs on the market right now it probably has 100 settings scattered across multiple, sometimes overlapping and conflicting menus, some of which may as well be an Easter egg they are so buried :(

Comment: the sharpness of text is bad, the edges are not smooth, and yeah modern TVs have these "service menus" that hide tons of the things you can disable :c